# Which file is the FcgidWrapper for Web Toolkit?

Tags: web-applications, configuration, wrapper, wt, mod-fcgid

I compiled WT (or witty or Web Toolkit) from source. Two of the files created are:

/lib/libwtfcgi.so (This is a soft link to build location)
/var/www/html/hello.wt

Which file is the FcgidWrapper? Or none of them?

The problem is: Instead of hello.wt example, I see an index page showing hello.wt file. When I click it, it just downloads it.

I think this problem is related with FcgidWrapper

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache2 :

1 - Enable the mod fcgid

2 - In the site definition :

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/html/
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

3 - Run the program in browser https://mysite/cgi-bin/hello.wt